# Abstracting filter `orderBy` functions in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-filter

So to keep our code as clean as possible and I'm assuming to prevent pollution of the global namespace I have to abstract my functions for my ctrls to a seperate file, however I'm having trouble abstracting one particular function which is ordering my widgets divs by the colour they receive from there CSV arrays, Red going first, Amber second and so forth.

#### Function that needs to be abstracted

```
$scope.colourOrder = function (x) {
    switch (x.colour) {
        case "Red":
            return 1;
            break;
        case "Amber":
            return 2;
            break;
        case "Green":
            return 3;
            break;
    };
```

#### HTML

```
ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy : colourOrder"
```

So at the moment this works perfectly fine in the relevant ctrl for the html, I just don't really have a clue how to abstract this function and then call it back into the Ctrl.

Any help with an explanation on how this process works would be highly appreciated.

Comment: create a custom filter, some good information here https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

Comment: Thanks Ric I'll have  a look at that and see if it helps

Comment: The point is that you can reuse the filter anywhere and test it in isolation if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters):

```
app.filter("orderByColour",function() {
    return function(xArray) {
        return xArray.sort((a,b) => colourOrder(a)-colourOrder(b));
    };
    function colourOrder(x) {
        switch (x.colour) {
            case "Red":
                return 1;
                break;
            case "Amber":
                return 2;
                break;
            case "Green":
                return 3;
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        };
    }
})
```

### Usage:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in friends | orderByColour">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{x.colour}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LU4lZs2Mx3lmBwSFa1Va?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [
        {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  colour: 'Red'},
        {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  colour: 'Green'},
        {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  colour: 'Amber'},
        {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  colour: 'Blue'},
        {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  colour: 'Green'},
    ];
})
.filter("orderByColour",function() {
    return function(xArray) {
        return xArray.sort((a,b) => colourOrder(a)-colourOrder(b));
    };
    function colourOrder(x) {
        switch (x.colour) {
            case "Red":
                return 1;
                break;
            case "Amber":
                return 2;
                break;
            case "Green":
                return 3;
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        };
    }
})
```

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in friends | orderByColour">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{x.colour}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```